# Link to route is not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, hyperlink, routes

I have to link to a route from a view file but it is not woriking.
Error is: page not found

{{ URL::route('routename') }}

but when i tried to access this by localhost/laravel/index.php/routename
then i can access that file. 
I have done
AllOverride all

also uncomment this line in httpd
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Answer (score 0):

You need to name your route

```
Route::get('user/profile', array(
    'as'   => 'profile', // This is the route's name
    'uses' => 'UserController@showProfile'
));
```

now you can call {{URL::route('profile')}}

Answer (score 0):

You need to need two things in C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\httpd
1) uncomment the line 
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
2)Change AllOverride none to AllOverride All

Thing i was missing is blade templete system..
rename the view file with blade.php extension